# Laravel 5 - how to get action names (for getting urls in templates with route() function) from routes defined using Route::controllers()?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel, and I'm trying to generate URLs using [named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#named-routes), but I can't find any documentation pertaining to this scenario.. I want to generate URLs to the default authentication based routes that Laravel ships with, but coming from [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) I really dislike the idea of generating URLs using the `url` function and specifying the path.. I like using a bound name that I give the route [(here are some examples from silex)](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/url_generator.html#usage), is there any way to specify a name (or is there a dynamic name I can use) to generate the URLs for routes defined using `Route::controller` or `Route::controllers`? For example, what would I pass to `route` in my template to generate the `logout` url?

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Would I just have to dig through the traits and manually specify each controller method if I want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the names for different controller actions when using `Route::controller`:

```
Route::controller('auth', 'Auth\AuthController', [
    'getLogin' => 'auth.login',
    'getLogout' => 'auth.logout',
    // and so on
]);
```

However you may also use the `action()` helper instead of `route()` or `url()`. It let's you specify the controller and method you want to generate an URL for:

```
action('Auth\AuthController@getLogin')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set pass your route names as an array in the 3rd argument to `controller`:

```php
Route::controller('auth', 'Auth\AuthController', [
    'getLogin' => 'auth.login',
]);
```

There's no way to mass assign them.